# Do not ignore duplicate email addresses for VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

In this code, the script will exclude duplicate email addresses.  I want the opposite, as I want to include duplicate email addresses and send them each a separate e-mail.  I do not know what part of the code to modify to get the intended result.

```html
 '**********You MUST DO THIS FIRST**********
'On the Tools menu, click References.
'In the Available References list, click to select the 'Microsoft Outlook 9.0 Object Library check box. Click OK.
'--- Set up the Outlook objects.
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim body As String
Dim T As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
    
'--- Declare our global variables to be used in each subroutine.
Dim CustomerAddress As String
Dim CustomerMessage As String

Sub MailItNow()
'--- Declare our variables.
Dim X As Integer
Dim TempCustomerAddress As String
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Select
Range("A1").Select

'--- Prevent screen redraws until the macro is finished.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'--- Sets which row to start searching for e-mail addresses and names.
X = 2

'--- Begin looping through all the e-mail addresses in column A until
'    a blank cell is hit.
While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X).Text <> ""

      
    '--- Increment X until a different e-mail address is found.
    While TempCustomerAddress = CustomerAddress
        X = X + 1
        CustomerAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X).Text
    Wend
    
    '--- Add the e-mail address to a global variable.
    CustomerAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X - 1).Text
    '--- Run the subroutine to send the message.

    '--- This is required to prevent a name which does not resolve to
    '    an e-mail address from hanging the app.
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create the message.
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\me\new.oft")
      
    f = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("B" & X - 1)
    g = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("C" & X - 1)
    h = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("E" & X - 1)
    j = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("D" & X - 1)
    k = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("F" & X - 1)
    l = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("G" & X - 1)
    m = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("H" & X - 1)
    n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X - 1)
    o = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("J" & X - 1)
    
    With objOutlookMsg
        ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(CustomerAddress)
        objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field1", f)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field2", g)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field3", h)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field4", j)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field5", k)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field6", l)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field7", m)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field8", n)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field9", o)
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance
    
       ' Add attachments to the message.
        If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
            Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
        End If
        
        ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
        For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
            objOutlookRecip.Resolve
            If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next
        .Send '--- Send the message.
    
    End With
    
    '--- Remove the message and Outlook application from memory.
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

Wend

End Sub
```

As you can see, there is a need to replace certain information within the e-mail template.

Comment: I would start off by not looping through your workbook, but create an array or collection of your email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

For one, do not loop each cell in your column. This is very inefficient. I would recommend you place in an array, then if you must you can loop that.

Also, while declaring workbook/worksheet/range objects is *technically optional*, it's far from being recommended that you not do this. For starters, if done **correctly** (as in using meaningful variable names), this can assist in making your code easier to read.

```
Sub test()

    ' For the love of Pete, declare your objects!!
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngI As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("day1")
    Set rngI = ws.UsedRange.Columns("I")

    ' This is your array that contains your emails
    Dim emailArr() As Variant, Email As Variant
    emailArr = rngI.Value

    ' Loop through each email and do what you need to do with it
    For Each Email In emailArr
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        'everything you do with this email goes here

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the entire code.  I think this answer would be correct, if I didn't have the replacements shown now.

Comment: @displayname I don't believe K.Davis's solution will work with replacing the information in the email.  This is my fault as I only posted the snippet at first.

Comment: @Yogwhatup, well, _first_ try it! and _then_, should any issue arise come back here